# className doesn't display my css changes in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I create a new nextjs project with typescript and made my first component, however when I'm trying to add custom styling in className it just doesn't apply it for some reason in the browser.

Here's my code:

```
import Link from 'next/link'

function Header() {
  return (
    <header>
        <div className="flex items-center space-x-5">
            <Link href="/">
                <img
                 className="w-44 object-contain cursor-pointer"
                 src="https://miro.medium.com/max/8978/1*s986xIGqhfsN8U--09_AdA.png"
                 />
            </Link>
            <div className="hidden md:inline-flex items-center space-x-5">
                <h3>About</h3>
                <h3>Contact</h3>
                <h3 className="text-white bg-green-600">Follow</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div> </div>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

main index.tsx:

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Header from '../components/Header'

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <Header />
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Do you use tailwind? I doesn't work if you don't setup tailwind properly. Here you can see how to setup tailwind in next's:  https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

Comment: Fixed it by reconfigure my tailwindcss thanks :)

Comment: same issue here. But without even using tailwind. I use my own css which is in public folder but next js does not update className at all.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use custom styling like this, either create a new css file or if you really want to use custom styling you should install [tailwind css](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) or you can use **inline styling using style prop in tags**

Comment: Fixed it by reconfigure my tailwindcss thanks :)