# TailwindCSS className does not display changes on browser in Next.js App

Tags: tailwind-css, next.js14

I am following this video trying to build a social media site with Next.js.
Problem is at this time in the video where he is building "onboarding" page.
https://youtu.be/O5cmLDVTgAs?t=3810

The classname styles in below page.tsx are not displaying on the browser.

Routing is: app/(auth)/onboarding/page.tsx

async function Page() {
return (

Onboarding

## Onboarding h1

Onboarding p

Complete your profile on OnlyAbroad

```
    </main>
)
```

}
export default Page;

=====================

when I inspect the browser, I see the classnames are there but they are not being applied in browser output.

I reinstalled Tailwind and followed procedure in this link but it did not help
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

I also saw a similar issue here on stackoverflow, but they did not show exactly what they did to fix it.
[className doesn't display my css changes in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73258509/classname-doesnt-display-my-css-changes-in-next-js)

The full code for the onboarding/page.tsx is here:
https://github.com/adrianhajdin/threads/blob/main/app/(auth)/onboarding/page.tsx

Here is the image of my inspection. How can I get Tailwind CSS styling to work ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMrgO.jpg)

I reinstalled Tailwind CSS
I used several Tailwind CSS styles but none works.
I was expecting the Tailwind CSS styles to take effect on browser

Comment: I actually found an answer. I added these two lines on my app/(auth)layout.tsx file.

import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import './globals.css'

above information is from this link under "app/layout.tsx" section
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/tailwind-css

My folder structure is as follows. above imports were in the app(root)layout.tsx file but were not in the app(auth)layout.tsx where my route app(auth)onboarding exists.

app(auth)onboarding
app(auth)layout.tsx
app(root)layout.tsx